# Create a list from another, filtering values and in Excel for Microsoft 365

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column A of values that works as a filter (1 or 2) for the column B, which is the attribute. I need to create a new column (C), of values based on the second column but filtered with the column 1, as follows:

[image: Example]
(values can be duplicates, as shown)

I tried the INDEX/MATCH formulas, without luck. I have not had any luck either with the Data/Filter menu options as I need column C to update automatically whenever a new value is entered into columns A and B.

Comment: What version of Excel have you got? With the new `FILTER` function this could be well easy.

Comment: Excel for Microsoft 365, 2008 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Office365` use filter formula.

```
=FILTER(B2:B8,A2:A8=1,"")
```

[image]

Without `Office365` use `Index()` and `Aggregate()`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$8,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$A$8)-ROW($A$1)/($A$2:$A$8=1),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! how was I not aware of this new feature of Office365. Thank you very much Harun!
Have a nice day!